# doctrine:mapping:import default naming strategy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to change the default naming strategy in building entity classes from an existing database in Symfony2. When we execute the command:

> php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml

our fieldnames are converted from CamelCase to lowercase. For instance the fieldname PmoItem is converted to pmoitem. Is there a way to preserve this and keep the fieldname PmoItem unchanged?

Answer (score 2):

You must change the function `getFieldNameForColumn()` in class `vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver.php`

Delete the following line:
`$columnName = strtolower($columnName);`

Comment: lifesaver. For classnames change `return $this->namespace . Inflector::classify($tableName);`